# Python binary search for element not in the array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, binary-search, assert

I'm using a binary search function to check the index of an element in an array, and using `assert` to confirm the element's index in the array...

```
arr = [-2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13]
assert search(arr, 11) == 6
assert search(arr, 14) == -1 
assert search(arr, -4) == -1
```

Obviously, `11` is located at index 6 in the array, so `assert search(arr, 11) == 6` runs True. But I want to learn how it is asserted that elements *not* in the array (in this case, `14` and `-4`) are indexed at -1?

Update: here is the implementation of the `search` method...

```
def search(arr, target):
    left = 0
    right = len(arr) - 1
    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2 # make sure to round it down
        if arr[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif target < arr[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    return -1
```

(This is not my code--I'm simply following a tutorial by CS Dojo on YouTube :)).

Comment: What's the implementation of your `search` method? I imagine it does a `return -1` if it can't find the element in the input.

Comment: Thanks, and you are correct. I updated my question to include the code for the `search` function.

Comment: Okay, so with the code, do you have a question? If the binary search fails to find `target` in `arr`, it will `return -1` and that's why your `assert` statements work.

Comment: Oh, I see the connection now--thank you! So that means the `return -1` statement essentially assigns a `-1 `index to all searches that don't appear in the array?

Comment: The important thing to understand is the `while` loop - if you're not familiar with [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) it tries to find an item in a sorted input sequence and then shrinking the search window each time it can't find the element. If the element _doesn't exist_, the loop eventually stops because `left <= right` isn't true anymore, and it will then do `return -1`. So yes, for any element `e` and input `input_list`, `search` returns `-1` if `e` does not exist in `input_list`.

Answer (score 0):

The Python standard library doesn't have `search()`, so you must be using something else.  It looks like it returns `-1` to signal a not-found condition rather than as a meaningful index.

This used to be a common convention.  Raising an exception is now more typical.  Here an [example taken from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists):

```
def index(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question to include the `search` function I used (following a tutorial).

Comment: @17spr The answer still applies.  The function used -1 as a special value rather than as an index.